# Can you interpolate path using react-router-dom v6 - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, react-router-dom

I am aiming to create a custom path using react router dom v6 whereby my child component passes a string to my parent component (via a function) and then my parent component puts the strings value as a /param in the routes path parameter.

I have had success with all of this up to the last ste. I cannot figure out how to interpolate my dynamic value into the paths value (which is a string) the way you would interpolate a value into a regular string for example.

In a regular string I would just do `Hello my URL is ${myurl}` But this is does not work when trying to do it in the path value. Is there another way particular to react router dom v6 to accomplish my same goal (putting a dynamic string from my state into the parameters of path)?

Although this is just a exercise to see if its possible to do something like this (string interpolation in react router dom v6 route params), what I am trying to accomplish with this bit of code in the bigger picture is have my child component (which has buttons that can be clicked on, feed my parent component the name of the button that was clicked and then have the parent component (App.js) put the name of that button in the URL. That is why I have a state called myurl. I want the URL name to change based on the button clicked in the child component.

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Genrenavbar from "./NavBars/Genrenavbar";
import { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const [myurl, Setmyurl] = useState("");

  console.log("My URL IS", myurl);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path=`/${myurl}` element={<Genrenavbar Setmyurl={Setmyurl} />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Also below is my Genrenavbar component for reference

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import useFetchgenrenavbar from "../utils/useFetchgenrenavbar";
import Moviedisplay from "./Moviedisplay";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Genrenavbar({ Setmyurl }) {
  const [mygenres, setMygenres] = useState({ genres: [] });
  const [myselectedgenre, setMyselectedgenre] = useState({});

  const mygottengenres = useFetchgenrenavbar();

  useEffect(() => {

    setMygenres(mygottengenres);
  }, [mygottengenres]);
 
  const help = mygenres.genres.map((elem) => console.log(elem.name));
  const trending = "Trending";
  const TopRated = "Top Rated";

  const myuseeffectfunction = useEffect(
    () => console.log("My selected genre is ", myselectedgenre.name),
    [myselectedgenre]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      {mygenres.genres.map((elem) => (
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setMyselectedgenre(elem);
            Setmyurl(elem.name);
          }}
        >
          {elem.name}
        </button>
      ))}

      <Moviedisplay myselectedgenre={myselectedgenre} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The route needs to have a valid path so it can be matched and render a routed component. I don't think this can be done with a single component alone and have it make sense. Can you edit your post to be something a little more representative of your *actual* use case? Is `Genrenavbar` trying to update the `myurl` state ***and*** navigate to *that* as a path value?

Comment: Yes, It is trying to update myurl and navigate to that as a path value. All my data processing is done in my genrenavbar component and its child components (which is why I pass the name up from the child component to the parent). I only want to display the name of the button in my child component in my URL when it is clicked. Currently everything is working great in my code except it comes of as a single page application(as URL params don't change when each button is clicked - although correct data is displayed when each button is clicked).

Comment: You might have better luck rendering two routes, one for `Genrenavbar` that it can link to, and the other using a dynamic path param for the button name. Remove the dependency on state out in the parent component.

Comment: Hmm, mind expanding what you mean? Do you mean one route that is used in the for the params (if a user puts in a param in the URL) and the other I am totally not sure what you meant there?. I am aware of how to pass down a param so to get the right output if it was directly put into the URL by a user, but I am not sure what you mean when it comes to the button explanation.

Comment: I was referring to something like `<Route path="/" element={<GenreBar />} />` and `<Route path="/:genre" element={???} />`. This was before you had updated your post to include the `GenreBar` component. Now I think you just need the one route you have and the `GenreBar` component just updates the URL via navigation actions. I can provide an answer with the second with more in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `myurl` state in the parent component is necessary. Instead of trying to pass down a state updater function to the child component it can issue navigation actions to a route with a dynamic route param.

Example:

App

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        ... other routes ...
        <Route path="/:genre" element={<Genrenavbar />} />
        ... other routes ...
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Genrenavbar

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Genrenavbar() {
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // <-- access navigate function

  const [mygenres, setMygenres] = useState({ genres: [] });
  const [myselectedgenre, setMyselectedgenre] = useState({});

  const mygottengenres = useFetchgenrenavbar();

  useEffect(() => {
    setMygenres(mygottengenres);
  }, [mygottengenres]);
 
  const help = mygenres.genres.map((elem) => console.log(elem.name));
  const trending = "Trending";
  const TopRated = "Top Rated";

  const myuseeffectfunction = useEffect(
    () => console.log("My selected genre is ", myselectedgenre.name),
    [myselectedgenre]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      {mygenres.genres.map((elem) => (
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setMyselectedgenre(elem);
            navigate(`/${elem.name}`); // <-- navigate to genre
          }}
        >
          {elem.name}
        </button>
      ))}

      <Moviedisplay myselectedgenre={myselectedgenre} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hello Drew, although this works in theory, why is it that when I launch my app, I have to manually put in a /elem-name to begin with before clicking on my elem buttons if I want my elem name to be displayed in the URL . Otherwise, I can click on my elem buttons and all the proper information will be displayed but the URL will not change.  Its like I need to manually get it going by putting an elem name in the URL and only then will everything work as expected. Any idea as to why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: @Learningiskey Sorry, I was assuming you had other routes that were used as entry points into the route rendering `Genranavbar`. It sounds like you are asking how to "bootstrap" the genre value in the URL. You can either (A) render a second route on `"/"` that also renders the `Genrenavbar` component, e.g. `<Route path="/" element={<Genrenavbar />} />` and the `genre` param will be simply undefined, or (B) redirect to the genre route with a dummy/default genre value, e.g. `<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/general" replace />} />`.